# How to remove outline dotted border with using css

Tags: html, css

[image]

I tried to remove outer dotted border with this CSS code but it does not work.

```
<div class="container-body"></div>

.container-body {
    outer-border: none;
}
```

Comment: outline: none - for outline... border: none - for border

Comment: Why do you care about that outline? Removing it may create bad user experiences, e.g. for mobile users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a `border` `dotted` use

```
.container-body{ 
   border:none;
}
```

Or it is outline use as per Mukesh Ram posted the answer

```
.container-body{ 
   outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.container-body{ 
   outline:none;
}
```